# Кнопка закрытия приложения

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

В приложении под iOS мне нужно создать кнопку, при нажатии на которую приложение закрывается. Каким образом я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Делать такую кнопку нельзя (приложение не пройдет ревью в AppStore). 
Приложение можно закрыть только кнопкой Home на айфоне.

Comment: +100500

Или, если это ентерпрайз акк и полюбому требуют и вы неможете отстоять свое, можно закрешить спецом))) Но это ай-яй-яй))

Comment: зачем крешить? exit(0) из си работает, проверено и как раз в описаной вами ситуации - энтерпрайс акк и "хочу-не могу выход при определенных условиях" :)

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно ничего создавать, она находится прямо под экраном)